# use sipgate Rest API to post a voicemail greeting

Tags: rest, perl, voip, internal-server-error

I've been trying to post a voicemail greeting using the sipgate Rest API. The request is sent to [https://api.sipgate.com/v2/{userId}/phonelines/{phonelineId}/voicemails/{voicemailId}/greetings](https://api.sipgate.com/v2/%7BuserId%7D/phonelines/%7BphonelineId%7D/voicemails/%7BvoicemailId%7D/greetings) .

Unfortunately the server returns a 500 error (Internal Server Error). Does anybody know this problem? Could it be a problem on the server-side of sipgate?
Cause other POST/GET requests work fine, just this one has some issue..
I couldn't find anything online about uploading voicemail greetings with sipgate Rest API, so any help is very much appreciated!

Here's a code-snippet with the request in Perl, the authentication is obviously incorrect for security reasons but the problem is not an authentication problem:

```
my $audio64 = encode_base64($audioData);
my $data = {filename => 'test.mp3', base64Content => $audio64};
my $encodedData = encode_json($data);
my $URL = "https://api.sipgate.com/v2/w0/phonelines/p0/voicemails/v0/greetings";   
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

$ua->ssl_opts( verify_hostname => 0, SSL_verify_mode => 0x00 );

$ua->timeout(20);
         
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(

   'POST',

   $URL,

   HTTP::Headers->new(

        Accept => "application/json",

        Authorization => "Basic dadada",

   ),

   $encodedData    
);

$req->content_type('application/json');    
my $rv = $ua->request( $req );
```

Comment: Nothing inherently wrong in there. Any docs for the API? (APIs should provide better error reporting!)

Comment: yes so: https://api.sipgate.com/v2/doc#

Comment: and https://developer.sipgate.io/rest-api/authentication/

Comment: Do you get a proper response if you list all voicemail greetings? Let's figure out if you can even do that part of it (so, checks auth and the various things you fill in for the endpoint).

Comment: Docs are at https://api.sipgate.com/v2/doc#/operations/phonelines/addGreeting

Comment: And, since I'm assuming that you're paying for this service, what does sipgate say about it?

Comment: @briandfoy yes I had already tried the get request and it works, so it's just the post request that doesn't work

Comment: @briandfoy they're not replying to my messages for over a week :D